How to add the instana span context to HTTP headers?
Service A got an instana span (say spanX) and I need to send this spanX to service B via an HTTP call to make a child span (say spanY) out of it. I read through and found that in OpenTelemetry TextMapPropagator can be used to inject span to HTTP headers. But couldn't find a doc or code snippet of it.
Service A
======
SpanX = tracer.start_span("parent")
part1. create a span context of SpanX to put in the http header

-> HTTP call to service B

SERVICE B
======
part2. Read the span context of SpanX from the HTTP header and create a child span, span Y out of it

How to do Part1 and Part2 is what I am exactly looking for.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

The easiest way to create a child span from spanX in another service is passing the trace_id and span_id from your spanX by adding the X-INSTANA-T and X-INSTANA-S in the headers of the request to your Service B, like :
headers = {
    "X-INSTANA-T": spanX.context.trace_id,
    "X-INSTANA-S": spanX.context.span_id,
}

resp = requests.get(
    "your-service-B-url_or_ip/",
    headers=headers,
)

